# Storing Collection result from mongoDB in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database

I am new to node and I have read the data from mongoDB successfully.

But I would like to store the whole data from the Collection into a variable in nodejs as I would like to use them in the index page.

I do not know how to store it.

```
// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);    
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    seriescollection = db.collection('series');    
});

var findseries = function (db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('series').find();
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            console.dir(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    //insertDocument(db, function () {});
    findseries(db, function () {
        db.close();
    });
});
```

My sample JSON object in MongoDb is

```
{
    "_id" : "b835225ba18",
    "title" : "Name",
    "imageurl" :"https://promotions.bellaliant.net/files/Images/TMN/Ballers-June2015.jpg",
    "namespaceId" : "UNI890"
}
```

I would like to access all the fields and create a page based on the fields that I have stored. I need to access all the fields and that is my main goal.

This is a pet project I am working on a leisure time to learn MEAN stack a bit.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues with this code, but I think what you're looking for is the `toArray` method:

```
var findseries = function (db, callback) {
  db.collection('series').find().toArray(function(err, allTheThings) {

    // Do whatever with the array

    // Spit them all out to console
    console.log(allTheThings);

    // Get the first one
    allTheThings[0];

    // Iterate over them
    allTheThings.forEach(function(thing) {
      // This is a single instance of thing
      thing;
    });

    // Return them
    callback(null, allTheThings);
  }
}
```

More here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/

And here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get allofthings as [object Object].....Not a complete array

Comment: Oh gezz, that was silly of me. It's probably a promise or something. You want a callback, as described here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray I've updated my code.

Comment: Thanks!! Works just fine

Comment: I had a typo in there... `forEach` not `foreach`. Is that the problem?